# Wrong target URL

Tags: weblogic, jersey-2.0, java-ee-6, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

I've configured my project to load at this URL:

```
http://localhost:7101/foo/rs/user/home
```

However, when I deploy the application through JDeveloper I can see this in the *Debugging: IntegratedWebLogicServer* tab within the IDE:

> ```
> Target Application WADL -- http://localhost:7101/foo/application.wadl
> Target URL -- http://localhost:7101/foo/user/home
> ```

Note the `/rs` part is missing. It's mostly cosmetic (the site loads correctly in the browser when you use the correct URL) but, apart from confusing, it might be a symptom of some configuration issue. Where does JDeveloper get this URL from?

---

These are some of the hopefully relevant settings:

- \ViewController\ViewController.jpr

  ```xml
  <hash n="oracle.jdeveloper.model.J2eeSettings">
      <value n="j2eeWebAppName" v="Foo-ViewController-webapp"/>
      <value n="j2eeWebContextRoot" v="foo"/>
  </hash>
  ```
- ViewController\public_html\WEB-INF\web.xml

  ```xml
  <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <filter>
      <filter-name>JpsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
      <param-name>enable.anonymous</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>JpsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.example.foo.view.rest</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature, org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
      <extension>js</extension>
      <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Jersey resources</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>valid-users</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
      <role-name>valid-users</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <ejb-local-ref>
      <ejb-ref-name>ejb/FooEJB</ejb-ref-name>
      <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
      <local>com.example.foo.model.FooEJB</local>
      <ejb-link>FooEJB</ejb-link>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <listener>
      <listener-class>com.example.foo.view.listeners.SessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  </web-app>
  ```
- com.example.foo.view.rest.UserService

  ```
  package com.example.foo.view.rest;


  import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;

  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;

  import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;

  import javax.naming.NamingException;

  import javax.ws.rs.GET;
  import javax.ws.rs.Path;
  import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


  @Path("user")
  @RolesAllowed("valid-users")
  public class UserService extends BaseService {
      public UserService() throws NamingException {
          super();
      }

      @GET
      @Path("/home")
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      public Response showHome() {
          Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
          map.put("title", "Home");
          return Response.ok(new Viewable("/user/home", map)).build();
      }
  }
  ```
- com.example.foo.view.rest.BaseService

  ```
  package com.example.foo.view.rest;


  import com.example.foo.commons.Constants;
  import com.example.foo.model.FooEJB;

  import javax.annotation.Resource;

  import javax.naming.InitialContext;
  import javax.naming.NamingException;

  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;


  public class BaseService {
      @Resource
      protected FooEJB fooEJB;
      @Context
      protected HttpServletRequest request;
      @Context
      protected HttpServletResponse response;
      @Context
      protected SecurityContext securityContext;

      public BaseService() throws NamingException {
          InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
          fooEJB = (FooEJB)context.lookup(Constants.EJB_JDNI_NAME);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: What is `foo` and what is `rs`? And can you show all your configuration?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I've added some settings into the question (`foo` is the context root and `rs` is the path prefix for Jersey-enabled routes). Please leet me know if you need further details.

Comment: Can you show everything related to configuration i.e. the whole web.xml, if you have a ResourceConfig/Application class

Comment: @PaulSamsotha There you are.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I suspect that JDeveloper merely concatenates context root (`<value n="j2eeWebContextRoot" v="foo"/>`) and `@Path` annotations. I have the impression that this IDE version does not support Jersey/2 and there's nothing I can do unless I upgrade the IDE or downgrade the library.